# Kindle Direct Publishing: How to mention other Books

Tags: kindle, epub, mobi, kdp

Somebody knows how I can create "View in Store" Links within my Kindle E-Books?

I noticed that some books I've bought on Amazon use these special type of links which have a little book symbol next to them. When I click on the link a modal window opens which shows a preview of the Book and three options:

- View in Store
- Try a Sample
- Add to wish list

Here is a Screenshot:
[image]

Beside that at the end of the book there is a section of "Books mentioned in this Book" which directly links to other Books that where mentioned in this one.

It seems that those things are related but I couldn't find anywhere on how to actually create these type of links.

Maybe somebody has an insight.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I don't see any documentation for this in the Kindle guidelines. https://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf

My best guess is that this is simply an external hyperlink which Amazon recognizes, something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EZ4B0UK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EZ4B0UK)

I'll test this on my own ebook and see whether I can duplicate it.

Finally, I don't think this feature is particularly useful. Having this book-buy link can be distracting.(I try to minimize the external links in my ebooks).

Comment: I tried with direct amazon links as I was suspecting that Amazon might just recognize them but unfortunately it doesn't. Instead it opens them within the kindle browser which is a less than ideal way. Beside that I think that its a very useful feature if you are mentioning a lot of other books inside your book. But only if the hyperlinks work like in the example